# Can we spend zakat on our street as its broken?

Tags: zakat

My house is third on the street, but my street is broken.  I also have to give a lot of money as zakat.  Can I spend my zakat there as I am developing society and not only me but the people on my street will benefit?

Answer (score 2):

### There are eight categories on which zakat must be spent on.

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> *“As-Sadaqaat (here it means Zakaah) are **only** for the Fuqaraa’ (poor), and Al‑Masaakeen (the poor) and those employed to collect (the funds); and to attract the hearts of those who have been inclined (towards Islam); and to free the captives; and for those in debt; and for Allaah’s Cause (i.e. for Mujaahidoon — those fighting in a holy battle), and for the wayfarer (a traveller who is cut off from everything); a duty imposed by Allaah. And Allaah is All-Knower, All-Wise”*
>
> ([al-Tawbah 9:60](https://quran.com/9/60))

The categories are:

> - **The poor**
> - **The needy(destitute)**
> - **Those that are employed to collect or administer (funds), i.e those who are appointed by the authorities**
> - **People who by giving zakat, you are trying to open their hearts towards Islam**
> - **A slave**
> - **To those in debt so that they can pay of the debt**
> - **To those who are fighting for Allah (valid jihadists)**
> - **The traveller who is lost or has no money, i.e a refugee so that they might be able to go back to their homeland.**

**Your question** about paying Zakat on mending your broken street is **NOT** included in these eight categories so you **CANNOT** pay zakat on that.

**End quote.**

---

### However,

**you can pay it as sadaqah(optional charity).**

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> *“O you who believe! Spend of that with which We have provided for you, before a Day comes when there will be no bargaining, nor friendship, nor intercession. And it is the disbelievers who are the Zaalimoon (wrongdoers)”*
>
> ([al-Baqarah 2:254](https://quran.com/2/254))
>
> *“O you who believe! Spend of the good things which you have (legally) earned, and of that which We have produced from the earth for you, and do not aim at that which is bad to spend from it, (though) you would not accept it save if you close your eyes and tolerate therein. And know that Allaah is Rich (Free of all needs), and Worthy of all praise”*
>
> ([al-Baqarah 2:267](https://quran.com/2/267))

It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said:

> *The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever gives charity equal to a date from good (halal) earnings – for Allaah does not accept anything but that which is good – Allaah will take it in His right hand and tend it for the one who gave it as any one of you tends his foal, until it becomes like a mountain.”*
>
> [Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 1344; Muslim, 1014]

These verses and hadith clearly explain that Sadqah is beneficial to the one gives it and will give them lots of reward.

And Allah knows best.